# Admin function / system using sql (pdo) & php?

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

Currently I have a website at http://heartfx.site.nfoservers.com & currently have a functional registration system being used on it that is safe and am now on my next task which is setting up an admin panel where it automatically adds each user with 0 as there admin level in the database and myself (making myself admin_level 2) I can direct to a page where I can add specific users as an admin (make  them admin_level 1) where they will then be able to post blog posts on our news page.

I know my very first step to do to get this going is add an admin_level in the database. As you can see in the screenshot [here](http://puu.sh/p9SrY/51ab8868ca.png). 
What I have come here to ask help with is how do I fetch what the individuals admin level is in php on my certain pages that I want? For example would like to use something like:

```
if (admin_level === 1) {
  // show a blog / forums post function here eventually
} elseif (admin_level === 2) {
  // display admin panel to change users admin_level
} else {
// display nothing to regular user
}
```

I know that isn't close to the correct code but that is just to show you an example of what kind of function I am aiming towards.You can view the project including the database.sql and all the project files [here.](https://github.com/lowheartrate/heartNetwork) I also go further into depth of what the admin functions / system will consist of  [here](https://github.com/lowheartrate/heartNetwork/blob/master/README.md).

I am assuming the first thing I need to do as well is connect to the database query which I am assuming should look something like the following:

```
$query = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT admin_level FROM users")
$query->execute();
```

but I am no sure exactly how to target the admin_level in the table and make sure that they are *admin_level 1* or *admin_level 2* to then prompt them to the proper / correct information on the website.

Thank you in advance,
  Codi B.-Smith

Comment: Did you have an SQL course in your college? If not, you have to take it ASAP.

Comment: @YourCommonSense No I am not currently attending college and most of what I know as far as php / sql / everything other then basic html I learned outside of college course / classes.

Comment: Well, I believe there are online courses available. Check Coursera

Comment: Your auth system needs more work. Someone could just set the `username` cookie to `admin`...